# sqs.recieveMessage not receiving even when messages in queue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

So i have 3 lambdas, one with an API event that triggers a lambda that pulls down around 50,000 objects and pushes them all to a queue.

The second lambda reads from the queue, 10 at a time, in a loop 30 times - meaning it reads, does stuff, invokes the third lambda, returns promise, then reads again - 30 times for a total of 300 reads in the time the lambda executes

The 3rd lambda takes the information from the queue and hits another endpoint with it.

The issue is in that second lambda...First i call a function that returns the number of messages in the queue and if it's more than zero i read them. However, even if there's 20,000 messages in the queue it often comes back with nothing. I'm not sure why.

I have `WaitTimeSeconds` set to 20 for long polling. Any help would be greatly appreciated, the docs claim i can read up to 3,000/second with a FIFO queue and i'm having trouble getting anywhere near that performance.

Here's the code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });
  getMessageCount(sqs)
    .then((messageCount) => {
      if (messageCount > 0) {
        mapSeries(range(0, 30), getMessages(sqs))
          .then((messageRes) => {
            callback(null, messageRes);
          })
          .catch(e => Promise.reject(e));
      }
      callback(null, 'No more messages');
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      callback(e);
    });
};
```

`getMessageCount` makes a call to `sqs.getQueueAttributes` and returns a promise that receives the number of messages.

`mapSeries` allows the loop to wait for the previous promise to be resolved/rejected before iterating and on each iteration it calls getMessages which calls `sqs.receiveMessage` and invokes the 3rd lambda with the data.

Any perspective on this is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your questions, the problem lies with getting the number of messages in the queue. If you had also given the `getMessageCount(sqs)` as well, we could have determined the types of attributes you are trying to retrieve from SQS.

There are three types of attributes relevant, to get the message count in SQS. These attributes are given below.

> **ApproximateNumberOfMessages** - Returns the approximate number of visible
>   messages in a queue
>
> **ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible** - Returns the approximate number of messages that have not timed-out and aren't deleted.

If you want to include the messages that are waiting to be added, you can consider the following property as well.

> **ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed** - Returns the approximate number of
>   messages that are waiting to be added to the queue.

By considering these attributes, you can get a much more accurate count from SQS.

Also if I may suggest, I implemented a similar system, but without looking for the count.I retrieve 10 messages at a time via polling, process them and delete them from the queue. As per your example, you can repeat this for 30 times. But if the `getMessages(sqs)` function returns an empty set, we could assume that the list is empty. (This depends on whether you are using short polling or long polling). Nevertheless, checking for the number of messages at every step seems to be redundant. This is according to this example, but it might defer according to the use case.

Comment: I'm using long polling and the message is `not` empty as `getMessages` returns a very large number and logs it out immediately before returning an empty set from the `getMessages` function.

Answer (score 0):

Read through the API documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#receiveMessage-property

Parameters:

MaxNumberOfMessages — (Integer)

> The maximum number of messages to return. Amazon SQS never returns
>   more messages than this value (however, fewer messages might be
>   returned). Valid values are 1 to 10. Default is 1.

Wrap your code in a while loop and anticipate a frequent case of 0 messages since 0 *is* fewer than 1 to 10.

Something like...

```
var messages = [];
while(messages.length < NUMBER_OF_MSGS_YOU_REALLY_WANT) {

    var new_messages = await getSQSMessages(NUMBER_OF_MSGS_YOU_REALLY_WANT - messages.length);
    if(new_messages.Data.Messages.length > 0) { 
       messages.push(new_messages.Data.Messages);
    }
}
```